# Perl - How to match millions of coupled strings?

Tags: arrays, perl, bioinformatics, fastq

I am very new to Perl and programming as a whole, therefore my terminology and coding ideas may come across as confusing or complete nonsense - on that note, please can you try to refrain from using jargon for my own understanding, thank you.

The context to my question is that I have a very large file (33GB) including multiple aspects of information, in-which I have already successfully split each column within the data into separate elements. A small snapshot of the data format is seen below:

```
HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1117:1997 1:N:0:CTTGTA 101 0 101 0
HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1117:1997 2:N:0:CTTGTA 101 0 101 0
HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1229:1999 1:N:0:CTTGTA 48 0 48 53
HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1229:1999 2:N:0:CTTGTA 77 0 77 24
HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1162:2000 1:N:0:CTTGTA 101 0 101 0
HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1162:2000 2:N:0:CTTGTA 101 0 101 0
HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1393:1965 1:N:0:CTTGTA 69 1 70 31
HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1393:1965 2:N:0:CTTGTA 101 0 101 0
```

This is my code for the original split:

```
open(FASTQ, "<", $input) or die "Failed to open '$input', $!\n";
while(my $line = <FASTQ>){
  chomp($line);
  my @columns = split(" ", $line); #Seperate columns by whitespace
  if($columns[5] > 0) {
    $n++; #Counts number of trimmed reads
```

My next move is to target the unique name ID `(element[0])`. As you can see, each unique ID comes in couples, one subsequently following the other. I want to try and get my program to match the first ID to its second identical ID. I have tried to make a new array of this element and then split this array by newlines:

```
foreach ($columns[0]){
          my @read_ID = split(/\n/);
          *Do something*
          }
```

I thought this would then separate each read ID into separate elements within `@read_ID`. I was then going to use `if(exists())` or `if($read_ID[0] == $read_ID[1])` to then test if the lines matched. Of course, I can already see the fundamental issue here - I would need to declare this for each and every line/element, within a file consisting of 33GB worth of these lines (150+ million). Therefore, I came to the conclusion that using the special variable `$_`, I can use the input of each line, allowing a continuous loop for each matching line. However, I realise that only the following line will match the original input, and thereafter it will continuously change for every 2 lines - killing the loop.

I am firstly asking if my method/idea even seems logical and appropriate and if it is, then how do I add in a loop that will allow 2 lines to be checked and then changed for the following 2 unique ID's? I hope this wasn't put across too confusingly, as I felt it would while typing this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Will.

Comment: Please add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of every Perl program -- especially when you are just starting.

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have mentioned previously - this is not my entire script and I have included both at the beginning of my script, just after the shebang.

Comment: unfortunately not, but I will look into it thanks.

Comment: You try to split `$columns[0]` with `\n` which holds `HWI-D00461:137:C9H2FACXX:4:1101:1117:1997` after split in first piece of the code  -- it does not look right. Perhaps it would be not a bad idea to add a header for each data field (or at least include it into description). You could split data into a hash what would be allow you utilize something like `$line->{id1}`, `$line->{year}`,`$line->{counter1}`,`$line->{something}`. Or you could split into set of variables in one go.

Comment: a hint: as pairs are subsequent, even & odd line numbers go together. accumulate the first append the second  process and emit the pair. rinse & repeat

Comment: Thank you both for your answers, they have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> each unique ID comes in couples, one subsequently following the other.

To read a file two lines at a time, you can use the following:

```perl
while (1) {
   defined( my $line1 = <$fh> )
      or last;
   defined( my $line2 = <$fh> )
      or die("Incomplete file\n");

   my @fields1 = split(" ", $line1);
   my @fields2 = split(" ", $line2);

   $fields1[0] eq $fields2[0]
      or die("Ids of lines ".( $. - 1 )." and $. don't match.\n");

   # ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has helped me enormously. In regards to how you've used the `defined` function - is this so once the loop reaches the end of the file it terminates? Also, I was just wondering, since I cannot find an answer elsewhere, if you keep defining the filehandle, will the script automatically interpret the filehandle as the next subsequent line in the file? Thanks again!